# Chat Agent Status Switching to Offline

Tags: community, chat, omnichannel

We have recently implemented Chat Agent/OmniChannel Routing in our Community site.

It works well so far, but we have found that the Agent Status is set to Offline if the Agent navigates to other tabs or windows for too long (about 30 minutes).

Is there any way to keep the Agent Status as Online indefinitely, so they can still receive new Chat requests, while they navigate through other tabs or windows?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation with OmniChannel.

You can upvote these two ideas asking for the ability to do this:

1. [Live Agent disconnects when a new SC browser tab is opened](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DrElAAK)
2. [Allow Omni-Channel to function across multiple browser tabs](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lJqrQAE)

Based on the official comment on #2, I wouldn't expect this to change any time soon.

There's 2 workarounds and they both really just serve to stop users from opening multiple tabs.

1. You can have users use the [Lightning Extension for Chrome](https://sfdc.co/LinkGrabber) which provides "link grabber". This essentially forces any link you click on that goes to Salesforce to open a new tab in your current console workspace (as opposed to opening a new Chrome tab).
2. Provide a confirmation prompt before logging out Agents in other browser tabs. This is mentioned in Summer '19 notes [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_omnichannel_promptbeforelogin.htm) and is within the Omni-Channel settings.

This doesn't really solve your issue if users have good reason and want to have open two separate chrome tabs of the console while staying logged in.